# Handling Errors in A Chain of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am using [`Q.js`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) as a promises library. Previously, theres code like:

```
function X() {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Users.find()
            .then(function(user) {
                Q.all([
                    getUserProfileInfo(user),
                    getUserSomethingElse(user)
                ])
                    .spread(function(profile, something) {
                        // do stuff

                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        // handle error for Q.all()

                        reject();
                    })
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                // handle error for User.find()

                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

But now I learnt that I can remove the nesting with something like:

```
function X() {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return Users.find()
            .then(function(user) {
                return Q.all([
                    getUserProfileInfo(user),
                    getUserSomethingElse(user)
                ]);
            })
            .spread(function(profile, something) {
                // do stuff

                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                // now how do I differenciate between 
                // the errors from Users.find() and Q.all()?

                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

The "problem" I have with the bottom (flattened) version is how do I differenciate the errors from `Users.find()` and `Q.all()`? Or in general possibly many other errors in the long `then` chain?

Currently I might use something like

```
function(err) {
    if (err.errors && err.statusCode) {
        // do something
    } else if (err.message) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But this is not really "nice" code isit? There must be a better way?

Comment: Related [What is the deferred antipattern and how do I avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with nesting if you want to differentiate errors in different parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple `catch` blocks, like this

```
function X() {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return Users.find()
            .catch(function(err) {
                 // Handle user finding error
                 throw new Error("Problem in finding users");
            })
            .then(function(user) {
                return Q.all([
                    getUserProfileInfo(user),
                    getUserSomethingElse(user)
                ]);
            })
            .spread(function(profile, something) {
                // do stuff

                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

Now, if there is a problem in finding the user, the first `catch` block will be executed and since you are throwing an `Error` from that, it will reach the next `catch` block in the chain. If there is no error in the `Users.find` then control will directly go to the `then` block.